# Initialization of a class object by assignment

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initialization, assignment-operator

I was doing some experiment today with the constructors:

```cpp
class cls
{
    int a;
public:
    cls(){cout<<"Default constructor called\n";}
    cls(int b){a=b;cout<<"Constructor with parameter called";}
}
```

Then this kind of initialization

```cpp
cls x=5;
```

yields an output saying that the constructor with parameter has been called.

My question i: what if I have a constructor with two or more parameters? Can I still use the initialization by assignment?

Comment: You can use `Foo x = {blah, blah};`.

Comment: By the way, your "initialization by assignment" is called *copy-initialization*.

Comment: I just tried your way and an error says it must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'

Comment: Could it be because of the version of my compiler? I am using TDM-GCC-64-5.1.0

Comment: Are you passing `-std=c++11` to the compiler?

Comment: `cls(int b){a=b;cout<<"Constructor with parameter called";}` --> `cls(int b) : a(b) {cout<<"Constructor with parameter called";}` - you want to *initialize* `a` in the *initialization list*, not default initialize it first and then subsequently assign to it in the constructor body. That's wasteful and won't even work for types that cannot be default constructed or cannot be assigned to.

Comment: @L. F. It works now. Plus, I don't think this is called copy initialization, because the variable on the right side of the assignment is not an object of the class. A copy initialization call the constructor first and then the copy constructor. But my initialization by assignment calls only once the constructor with parameter(s) once

Comment: @trisct *Copy-initialization* is a standard term-of-art that doesn't directly relate to copy constructors.

Comment: @trisct See [\[dcl.init\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#def:copy-initialization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do the same with more parameters like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class cls
{
    int a;
    double b;
public:
    cls(){std::cout<<"Default constructor called\n";}
    cls(int a): a(a){std::cout<<"Constructor with parameter called";}
    cls(int a, double b) : a(a), b(b){std::cout<<"Constructor with two parameter called";}
};

int main()
{
    cls t = {1, 1.5};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the difference between using () and {} here?

Comment: I don't think you understand the question.  This isn't copy-initialization.

Comment: @L.F. this is *direct initialization*, isn't it?

Comment: @ElProfesor Yes.

Comment: @trisct {} is a list initialization you can change it to copy initialization by using `cls t = {a, b};`

Comment: @L.F. I changed to copy-list-initialization

Comment: @trisct the cpp core guidelines recommend using initializer list: https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#es23-prefer-the--initializer-syntax